# Google AdSense error: "Earnings at risk - You need to fix some ads.txt file issues...", even though they're there

Tags: google-adsense

OK, I have Been seeing this forever.

> Earnings at risk - You need to fix some ads.txt file issues to avoid
> severe impact to your revenue.

The ads.txt file is located on every site and was downloaded from my Google AdSense panel years ago. All my sites have had this file in the root, which is accessible when you type in domain.com.ads.txt.

Why do I continue to see this error when it is in all my domain's root folders?

It shows that all my domains are at risk, so it is almost like Google does not or cannot see the files, but when I type in the https://www.example.com/ads.txt, they are all there.

Any insight on this would be great.

Comment: It's not saying that they cant be read.    Perhaps it's the format.

Comment: I think I might have just figured it out. I went to view the ads.txt file on one of the sites without WWW, and it did not find it. On my site(s), you have to use WWW. So, That MIGHT be the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just checked, and the ads.txt file can only be viewed if WWW is attached to the URL.
Bindings in IIS have both WWW.example.com and example.com for HTTP and HTTPS, and the DNS records have with and without.

I have three ARR Servers since I am running an IIS Server Farm.
The Bindings for the default site have ALL domains listed except those without the WWW.

I will update this Answer if the Warning goes away.

**UPDATE - January 31, 2023**
For anyone running a Server Farm on Windows or any other Server, make sure you have listed all the domains with and without WWW (HTTP and HTTPS) in the ARR Server Bindings for the Default Website.
This is a must for making sure Google can work properly with your site, and let's face it, not everyone types in the WWW.

So glad to have finally figured this one out after dealing with it over the last few years. AND I have noticed that Ads are running as they are supposed to on the pages as well, compared to not hardly running at all in the past. A lot of monies lost.

Comment: This was it. After a few days, all but one was lifted, and I just added that last link, which I overlooked the other day inside the ARR server's Bindings, and all is well.